# How can we break a number into a sum of primes raised to some power?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I am aware that we can do a [Prime Power Decomposition](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/prime-power-decomposition) on a number, for example

$1008 = 2^4 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 7^1$

In a book I’m reading, it is given that

$641 = 2^4 + 5^4$

How can we break a number into a sum of primes raised to some power?

In general, how can we find $n = p^n + q^m + \ldots$?

Please note that $641$ is prime.

Comment: Distinct and positive exponents, you cannot always do it: $6$ cannot be expressed as a sum of positive powers of distinct primes.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Ok thanks

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: In general, it is a very hard problem to split integers into sums of primes, prime powers, or say something about such a split. The Goldback conjecture and the ABC are two extremely difficult conjectures that say something about this problem.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Doesn't it appear that $6$ is the only actual example?

Comment: @QC_QAOA ok thanks for the information.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to clarify the following.  Do you allow primes to the power $1$, eg $5=2^1+3^1$?  Do you allow the same prime to different powers, eg $90=3^4+3^2$, or more than once to the same power, eg $18 = 3^2+3^2$?